# ember.js: dynamic segments and queries

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I have a problem with resources in ember.js.

given these router:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route "index", path: "/"
  @resource "transport_documents", ->
    @resource "transport_document", path: ":transport_document_id"
```

and this routes:

```
App.TransportDocumentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.TransportDocument.find()

App.TransportDocumentRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params)-> 
    App.TransportDocument.find(params.id)
```

- when i navigate to `/transport_documents` my server side call is: `/api/transport_documents`, as expected
- when i navigate to `/transport_documents/1` i expect this call is done:  `/api/transport_documents/1`, but it's not. no calls to my server

Is it an expected situation?
if no, what should i do to force my app doing this query? I want more details in the show view, and less in the index.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` will contain the dynamic segment name you specified.  In your case you need to use:

```
model: (params)-> 
  App.TransportDocument.find(params.transport_document_id)
```

See [this example](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models) in the Ember routing guide for more information.

Comment: changed. still no server calls if i NAVIGATE to that path passing from the index. It does a server call if i ACCESS directly to the url `/transport_documents/1`

Comment: try calling `App.TransportDocument.find(1)` manually and see if it hits your server

Comment: it does. (edited the comment before). Maybe he thinks i already have all data i could need?

Comment: if you are using `linkTo` or `transitionTo` you need to pass the `TransportDocument` object and then it should work the same as if you were requesting the object using `find(transport_document_id)`

Comment: isn't it in this way? 
{{#each controller}}{{#linkTo transport_document this}}{{/each}}. The href he builds is correct (`transport_documents/1`)

Comment: that seems correct, what goes wrong when that happens? it won't hit your server again since you've already loaded it. the `model` hook is only called when you are directly navigating using the URL

Comment: Nothing wrong. I just would like another request to be performad. So how can i call my model also when i'm browsing to that url?

Comment: 2 issues: 1, model won't be called every time since you are passing the object when using linkto, so you can use the `setupController` hook which is called every time. 2, issuing a `find(id)` call twice will result in the cached object being returned the second time, so you need to find a way to force ember-data to reload the model.

Comment: very well. I know something more about ember now. thank you @c4p

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep the @c4p answer as correct, because it helped me, but here's the trouble:

It depends on what ember-data library version you use.

See [Here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md) to see how it expects your associated models to be formatted